# Magento Collection - setOrder and getFirstItem

Tags: magento, collections

I am writing a Plugin and added a own db table to the magento database.

Now i want to get some data in sorted order from the table and i added the code bellow.

But everytime i dump the result of the last line i get the data in the order they are in the table not sorted by the given parameter. Can anyone help me with this?

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
$collection->setOrder(array('fieldname' =>  'asc', 'fieldname' =>  'desc'));
$collection->getFirstItem()->getData();
```

Comment: $collection->setOrder('fieldname' =>  'asc');

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call **setOrder** function multiple times for different columns.

```
$collection = $this->getCollection()
        ->setOrder('fieldname', 'asc')
        ->setOrder('fieldname2');
```

**Note**:  Direction DESC will be used by default.

Comment: Thank you for the warning about the default direction. Without that I probably would have thought my code simply wasn't doing anything.

After roughly 5 years of working with Magento I'm still frequently amazed at how it manages to make everything so complicated, including its database abstraction: "Hey here's an idea, you know this default that's been a constant in SQL for about 50 years, and is so familiar to every IT professional everywhere that they don't even have to think about it? Let's change it!"

Comment: @DougMcLean I guess you didn't try Drupal ;) From their point of view, a category is called taxonomy OooO